# How to get notification at a specific time?

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-alarms

I a trying to get a notifcation to fire at a specific time. I am using `AlarmManager` and `BroadcastReceiver` for this.In main activity `AlarmManager` calls the `BroadcastReceiver` but I cannot get the notification to fire from that class. It is giving me an error in the line
`nm=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);`
I don't know what to do.

Here's my code

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            long current_time=System.currentTimeMillis();
            Calendar time9=Calendar.getInstance();
            time9.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,16);
            time9.set(Calendar.MINUTE,30);
            time9.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
            Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,ScheduledReciever.class);
            PendingIntent pintent=PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent,0);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            long interval = 60 * 1000; //
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,time9.getTimeInMillis(), interval, pintent);
            finish();

    }}`
```

BroadcastReciever

```
`public class ScheduledReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
    static final int uniqueId=1234;
    NotificationManager nm;


    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        nm=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        String body="i hope this works";
        String title="trying";
        Intent it=new Intent(context,SecondActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pit=PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, it,0);
        Notification n=new Notification(R.drawable.att,body,System.currentTimeMillis());
        n.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, body, pit);
        n.defaults=Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
        nm.notify(uniqueId, n);

    }

}
```

Comment: post your log cat error

Comment: replace your line : nm=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE); with this one : nm = (NotificationManager) context
    .getSystemService(Activity.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

Comment: BY Activity...you mean which activity...the one in which i have the alarm manager or the current one or the one which it is going to open???

Answer (score 0):

Use the context passed:

```
nm=(NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

instead of:

```
nm=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

Comment: Can you please post the stacktrace or the error from logcat , Also try my edit in the answer